# Quality GL entries in vcf file

Tags: vcf, structural-variation

I have a `vcf v4.2` file with structural variants, the 8 columns describing the variant are clear, but in the genotype information I got confused by values of `GL` entries. In the [vcf specification](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) they mention that `GL` are likelihoods of the individual genotypes, but as far as I am concerned, likelihood should be a number between 0 and 1, therefore I am suprised to see negative numbers. Then I thought that it might be log-likelihood, but then it's strange that the higher the number is the better. Here is a sample of 5 variants with various called genotypes

```
...       GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV   0/1:-22.4949,0,-4.49485:45:PASS:20:1:11:0:1:4:0:0
...       GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV   0/1:-3.1888,0,-43.9892:32:PASS:16:26:13:2:9:2:0:0
...       GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV   0/1:-0.190635,0,-49.2888:4:LowQual:26:51:31:2:10:1:0:0
...       GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV   0/0:0,-1.01435,-75.899:10:LowQual:18:54:26:2:14:1:0:0
...       GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV   1/1:-19.198,-1.5031,0:15:PASS:70:0:58:0:0:5:0:0
```

The `vcf` file was generated by [delly](https://github.com/dellytools/delly) genotyper. I followed their recommendations for germline SV calling. However, negative likelihoods are even in the `vcf` specification, therefore it seems that it's not something `delly` specific.

So, what exactly is `GL` in `vcf` files? And how do they relate to other entries `GP` (genotype posterior probabilities, not in the file by delly) and `GQ` (conditional genotype quality)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VCF spec](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) clearly states that these are indeed log likelihood values:

> • GL : genotype likelihoods comprised of comma separated floating point log10-scaled likelihoods for all possible
>   genotypes given the set of alleles defined in the REF and ALT fields. In presence of the GT field the same
>   ploidy is expected and the canonical order is used; without GT field, diploidy is assumed. If A is the allele in
>   REF and B,C,... are the alleles as ordered in ALT, the ordering of genotypes for the likelihoods is given by:
>   F(j/k) = (k*(k+1)/2)+j. In other words, for biallelic sites the ordering is: AA,AB,BB; for triallelic sites the
>   ordering is: AA,AB,BB,AC,BC,CC, etc. For example: GT:GL 0/1:-323.03,-99.29,-802.53 (Floats)

With log-likelihood values, the higher the number, the better the value. So -2 is better than -3.

Comment: Dang, sometimes I get stuck in so complicated thoughts, while just the basic premise is wrong!

Comment: @KamilSJaron join the club! That happens to _all_ of us :)